# Hyperledger fabric test-network error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm trying to follow [Writing yout first application tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/write_first_app.html), but I always get some errors that I don't know how to solve. When creating network with **./network.sh up createChannel -c mychannel -ca**, I get error:
`Error: Post "https://localhost:7051/participation/v1/channels": dial tcp [::1]:7051: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I think that is because my docker images are not running at the moment and I can't start them manually because they immediately stop running.
So I started network with **./network.sh up**, and when the network is up I tried to make channel with CA with **./network.sh up createChannel -c mychannel -ca**, but I get next error.

```
$ ./network.sh createChannel -c mychannel -ca
    Creating channel 'mychannel'.
    If network is not up, starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb
    Generating channel genesis block 'mychannel.block'
    /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen
    + configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -channelID mychannel
    2021-07-04 20:48:01.621 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
    2021-07-04 20:48:01.642 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: etcdraft
    2021-07-04 20:48:01.642 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:16777216
    2021-07-04 20:48:01.642 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 004 Loaded configuration: C:\Users\marij\fabric-samples\test-network\configtx\configtx.yaml
    2021-07-04 20:48:01.661 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 005 Generating genesis block
    2021-07-04 20:48:01.661 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 006 Creating application channel genesis block
    2021-07-04 20:48:01.664 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Writing genesis block
    + res=0
    Creating channel mychannel
    Using organization 1
    + osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7051 --ca-file /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
    + res=1
    + osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7051 --ca-file /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
    + res=1
    + osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7051 --ca-file /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
    + res=1
    + osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7051 --ca-file /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /c/Users/marij/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
    + res=1
    Error: Post "https://localhost:7051/participation/v1/channels": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Can someone help me because I'm becoming desperate.

Docker:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                   PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
7f0e3eede2ff   hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"              46 seconds ago   Up 45 seconds                                                                                                   cli
75f54baf5b97   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"                48 seconds ago   Up 47 seconds            0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp, :::7050->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp, :::7053->7053/tcp   orderer.example.com
7c27e21bcd91   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        48 seconds ago   Up 47 seconds            7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp, :::9051->9051/tcp                                    peer0.org2.example.com
dc39c53222d3   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        48 seconds ago   Up 45 seconds            0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, :::7051->7051/tcp                                              peer0.org1.example.com
c3ac36198cb8   graphprotocol/graph-node:latest     "/bin/sh -c start"       7 days ago       Exited (1) 7 days ago                                                                                           relaxed_mahavira
97ac82818ee5   postgres:12                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago      Up 44 minutes            0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp                                              postgres
db02ee15750d   4885c2bc6c0e                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 weeks ago      Exited (0) 5 weeks ago                                                                                          nest-api
57c878b18e20   docker/getting-started              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 weeks ago      Exited (0) 6 weeks ago                                                                                          confi
```

Comment: did you try to delete the folders that were created, stop the containers (`docker ps -aq | xargs docker kill`),  delete the containers (`docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm`) and re-run everything again?

Comment: Thank you very much! The network started successfully after I did that!